# May you use an electric baby swing in Shabbos?

Tags: shabbat, baby-infant

Is it allowed on Shabbos to place a baby in and out from a battery operated swing that is designed to swing itself.
Of course the switch is turned on before Shabbas.

Maybe it’s the same as going in and off from an escalator/elevator , or is there any difference and sources to allow for a baby?

Comment: one opinion, not explanation http://askhalacha.com/index.php/ufaqs/hi-rabbi-allowed-put-baby-baby-swing-shabbat-leave-swing-shabbat-timer-allowed-not-can-unplug-swing-just-put-baby/

Comment: Good luck getting an answer to such a specific question like that! Almost everyone sticks warm food in the fridge not worrying about the extra power draw. Many people avoid shabbos elevators. Everything else in between....

Comment: There are also wind up swings that use a spring or something to store energy.  That could be an acceptable option.  Can one load a spring on Shabbos? Is it like a temporary knot or something?  I honestly don't know. I think you can use a screen door that slams itself shut.

Comment: You’ll burn out the motor really quickly that way, unless the batteries run out on their own first.

Answer (score 1):

As long as putting the baby in the swing would not cause any extra melacha to be done, this would be permitted. The same is true of the Shabbos elevator - those who forbid its use do so only out of concern that the force of the person entering the elevator may cause lights to illuminate and such like.

Comment: "As long as putting the baby in the swing would not cause any extra melacha to be done, this would be permitted. The same is true of” literally everything

Comment: Even if ,wouldn't it be a grama?

Comment: DoubleAA, you are right but it seems that the questioner was not aware.

Comment: Sam, depending on exactly how it worked you might be right - once there is more information this can be answered intelligently.